# All pages lead to home

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect, windows

I've recently moved from linux to windows hosting, and now all of my permalinks just redirect to the homepage. I've selected the correct structure in Settings->Permalinks and have the following in my web.config. Hopefully I'm making a daft mistake - any ideas?

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!--rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule-->
      <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
      </rule>
            <rule name="wordpress alt">
                <match url="^/(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="wordpress2">
                <match url="(?!index\.php|wp-|xmlrpc)(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reset the permalink setting to *Default*, then change it back to the custom structure I was using. This apparently resets it.